# Sometimes request.session.session_key is None

Tags: python, django, session, django-sessions

I hit a problem when get session_key from `request.session`.

I am using Django1.8 and Python2.7.10 to set up a RESTful service.

Here is snippet of my login view:

```
user = authenticate(username=userName, password=passWord)
if user is not None:
    # the password verified for the user
    if user.is_active:
        # app_logger.debug("User is valid, active and authenticated")
        if hasattr(user, 'parent') :
            login(request, user)
            request.session['ut'] = 4 
            # user type 1 means admin, 2 for teacher, 3 for student, 4 for parents
            request.session['uid'] = user.id
            description = request.POST.get('description','')

            request.session['realname'] = user.parent.realname
            request.session['pid'] = user.parent.id
            devicemanage.update_user_device(devicetoken, user.id, ostype, description) 
            children = parentmanage.get_children_info(user.parent.id)
            session_id = request.session.session_key
            user.parent.login_status = True
            user.parent.save()
            return JsonResponse({'retcode': 0,'notify_setting':{'receive_notify':user.parent.receive_notify,'notify_with_sound':user.parent.notify_with_sound,'notify_sound':user.parent.notify_sound,'notify_shake':user.parent.notify_shake},'pid':user.parent.id,'children':children,'name':user.parent.realname,'sessionid':session_id,'avatar':user.parent.avatar,'coins':user.parent.coins})
```

Now when this function is called, I see sometimes `session_id` is `None` within the response.

So, after debugging (I set breakpoint at the `return JsonResponse(...)` line), I see that when I hit the breakpoint the `request.session._session_key` is `None`, but `request.session.session_key` is `u'j4lhxe8lvk7j4v5cmkfzytyn5235chf1'` and `session_id` is also `None`.

Does anyone know how can this happen? Why isn't the value of `session_key` set when assigning it to `session_id` before returning the response?

Comment: If `request.session.session_key` is None, that means the session object is brand-new and hasn't been saved to the db yet.  Calling `request.session.save()` should populate that attribute.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

According to John's suggestion.

I fixed the problem by this snippet:

```
if not request.session.session_key:
    request.session.save()
session_id = request.session.session_key
```

Comment: but how did it saved if i refresh the same page??

Comment: OK. But I'll be checking this everywhere in my code that I want to use `session_key`?

Answer (score 11):

As per [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/sessions/):

> SessionStore.create() is designed to create a new session (i.e. one
>   not loaded from the session store and with session_key=None). save()
>   is designed to save an existing session (i.e. one loaded from the
>   session store). Calling save() on a new session may also work but has
>   a small chance of generating a session_key that collides with an
>   existing one. create() calls save() and loops until an unused
>   session_key is generated.

Means it is safer to use `create()` instead of `save()`. So you can try like this:

```
if not request.session.session_key:
    request.session.create()
session_id = request.session.session_key
```

Comment: The docs are wrong here, if you look at the code (at least for the db backend) when the session is new, calling save calls create, so theres no chance of colliding ids. So its better to directly call save and avoid the "if" part