# What to return to django admin if user has not username or something else

Tags: python, django, authentication

In short i am doing online store and in django admin i display authenticated users 'username' but there are users which didn't authenticated

So if authenticated users will order something it's okay i have their data.
But if unauthenticated users will order? What to show in django admin?
If i will request from user only his name from this no result. Because we know django need full authorization

**models.py**

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through=CartProduct)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Cart'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Cart'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username # That for authenticated users
```

**views.py**

```
class CartView(View):

    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        cart_id = request.session.get('cart_id')
        if cart_id == None:
            cart = Cart()
            cart.save()
            request.session['cart_id'] = cart_id

        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=cart_id)
        product_id = request.GET.get('product')
        delete_product = request.GET.get('delete')
        if product_id:
            product_instance = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
            amount = request.GET.get('amount')
            cart_product = CartProduct.objects.get_or_create(cart=cart, product=product_instance)[0]

            if delete_product:
                cart_product.delete()
            else:
                cart_product.amount = amount
                cart_product.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use IP adress, but that could be confusing / multiple people could share one.

So my suggestion would be to use Django's built-in [session framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/).

Pulling from [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526179/in-django-how-can-i-find-out-the-request-session-sessionid-and-use-it-as-a-vari), you'll see that you can gather the current session key from the `request` object.

Then it's just a matter of changing your Cart model :

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session

class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    session = models.ForeignKey(Session, null=True, blank=True)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through=CartProduct)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Cart'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Cart'

    def __str__(self):
        if self.user :
             return self.user.username # For for authenticated users
        else if self.session :
             return self.session.session_key
        else :
             return "Anonymous"
```

And of course, you'll need to make sure that you **add the request.session to your Cart object** when you create it.

Finally, it seems the session object can still be empty sometimes, so you should look at force-saving it if you really don't want an "Anonymous" line in your admin. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39181655/sometimes-request-session-session-key-is-none) makes force-saving the session quite simple :

```
if not request.session.session_key:
    request.session.save()
session_id = request.session.session_key
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a dispatch method inside the class so that you can check wether the user is authenticated
 `request.user.is_authenticated`
will return the status of user authentication. If the user is not authenticated then save the user as your need